# Cypher query execution time with Neo4j java driver

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher, neo4j-java-api

I am trying to find out execution time of my Cypher query with java driver.

```
Session session = driver.session();
session.run( "CREATE (a:Person {name:'Arthur', title:'King'})" );
StatementResult result = session.run( "Profile MATCH (a:Person) WHERE a.name = 'Arthur' RETURN a.name AS name, a.title AS title" );
```

But I could not find it anywhere in the [StatementResult](https://neo4j.com/docs/api/java-driver/current/org/neo4j/driver/v1/StatementResult.html) or in the [ResultSummary](https://neo4j.com/docs/api/java-driver/current/org/neo4j/driver/v1/summary/ResultSummary.html), which is returned by `StatementResult.consume(query)`.

I could access db hits from `ProfiledPlan` in `ResultSummary` but there is no information about time.

Is there any way I can access Cypher query execution time using neo4j java driver?

Comment: Hi, can you please in simple terms tell me what the `a` before create person `CREATE (a:Person ...` stands for. I keep seeing it allover. Is it similar to a statefield in JPQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Neo4j Java driver version 1.1.0 there is:

```
/**
 * The time it took the server to make the result available for consumption.
 *
 * @param unit The unit of the duration.
 * @return The time it took for the server to have the result available in the provided time unit.
 */
long resultAvailableAfter( TimeUnit unit );

/**
 * The time it took the server to consume the result.
 *
 * @param unit The unit of the duration.
 * @return The time it took for the server to consume the result in the provided time unit.
 */
long resultConsumedAfter( TimeUnit unit );
```

It provides you with both times:

1. Time till first byte
2. Full execution time including consuming data from server

Methods are localted on `org.neo4j.driver.v1.summary.ResultSummary` interface.

Comment: Thanks @arezoo you are right. I missed it because it is only available in the latest neo4j-java-driver 1.1.0 and I was using 1.0.5

Comment: Hi, can you tell me how ResultSummary was integrated in your code? Please