# How can I get the execution time of a query?

Tags: php, neo4j, graphaware

Can't find it in the `result->summarize()` data...
any ideas how to fetch the time directly?
It seems like there is something like `long resultAvailableAfter( TimeUnit unit )` see there: [Cypher query execution time with Neo4j java driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41401424/cypher-query-execution-time-with-neo4j-java-driver)
can i access a similar on php?

Comment: You can also execute the query directly from PhpMyAdmin's SQL tab, it shows you the execution time.

Comment: it's about neo4j with php, not MySQL ;)

Answer (score 1):

A common way to do this in PHP is to get the time() before you execute the query, and then get the time() after you execute the query, and then just find the difference between them. It won't be strictly query execution time since there is some overhead from your connection, etc...but should be very close.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php

Comment: already tried that way, but got huge impact on the time from connection and receiving results, compared to the displayed time in the cyper console in the web interface...

since i want to compare against arango, which provides real execution time, it doesn't solve my problem :(

Comment: When I want to compare, I prefer to create my own monitoring tool with the `time()` method, than to compare the query execution time from of two products. With that I'm sure to compare two identical units/things.

Comment: This might be what you are looking for:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/23378256/493739